# select top values in a column based on the variable name in another column

Tags: perl, unix, awk

I am trying to select top values in a column based on the variable/field in another column. it is a very large tab delimited file.

Input:

```
Names col2 col3 col4  
A    A1   def  10  
A    A1   BBB  10  
A    A1   CED  10  
A    A1   fff  7.5  
B    B1   def  7.5  
B    B1   dff  5.5  
B    B1   fff  4.5  
C    C1   ggg  6.5  
C    C3   iii  6.5  
C    C2   hhh  5.0  
C    C4   toi  6.5  
D    D1   xyz  10.0  
D    D2   ikj  7.5  
D    D3   abc  7.5  
...
```

Output

```
Names col2 col3 col4  
A    A1   def  10  
A    A1   BBB  10  
A    A1   CED  10  
B    B1   def  7.5  
C    C1   ggg  6.5  
C    C3   iii  6.5  
C    C4   toi  6.5  
D    D1   xyz  10.0
```

Basically, I want all the rows with values 10 and the top values for each of the names in column1. Any inputs to solve this by perl, awk or sed are well appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! We prefer if you put in some effort to find a solution before asking here. Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: I am beginner with bioinformatics. I tried using  perl with while loop and If $_[3] > "10". I stopped there as I did not know how to select based on a top value for each name.

Comment: You should show us the code and we can help with that.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the below code which worked and fetching the result

```
#!/bin/sh

for col1 in `grep -v "Names" <filename> |awk '{print $1}'|sort|uniq`;
 do 
     maxVal=$(awk -v x=$col1 '$1 == x {print $4}' <filename> |sort|uniq|head -1);
    awk -v names=$col1 -v max=$maxVal '$1 == names && $4 == max {print $0 }' <filename>
done
```

It produce results like below

```
A    A1   def  10  
A    A1   BBB  10  
A    A1   CED  10  
B    B1   fff  4.5  
C    C2   hhh  5.0
```